# how to fix CUDA cuInit: Unknown CUDA error value?

Tags: cuda, google-colaboratory, blender

I using colab on blender rendering GPU

suddenly it appear warning

how i fix it out?

```
CUDA cuInit: Unknown CUDA error value
F0523 17:11:21.172250   499 device.cpp:402] Device does not support queues.
*** Check failure stack trace: ***
    @          0x2b6cefd  (unknown)
    @          0x2b6ee03  (unknown)
    @          0x2b6ca8d  (unknown)
    @          0x2b6f6d9  (unknown)
    @          0x2b8e120  ccl::Device::gpu_queue_create()
    @          0x3390629  ccl::PathTraceWorkGPU::PathTraceWorkGPU()
    @          0x338ad04  ccl::PathTraceWork::create()
    @          0x33843e2  (unknown)
    @          0x33846c6  ccl::PathTrace::PathTrace()
    @          0x331b6e1  ccl::Session::Session()
    @          0x2b0cdd5  ccl::BlenderSession::create_session()
    @          0x2b0d990  ccl::BlenderSession::reset_session()
    @          0x2b0579d  (unknown)
    @          0x9eca874  (unknown)
    @          0x9e84cd8  _PyObject_MakeTpCall
    @          0x112b66f  _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault
    @          0x9f43364  (unknown)
    @          0x112b61a  _PyEval_EvalFrameDefault
    @          0x9f43364  (unknown)
    @          0x9e8495f  PyVectorcall_Call
    @          0x1a4d828  (unknown)
    @          0x19c0d66  (unknown)
    @          0x977aec9  (unknown)
    @          0x977bb04  RE_engine_render
    @          0x977f637  (unknown)
    @          0x97826a0  (unknown)
    @          0x978325c  RE_RenderAnim
    @          0x112e010  (unknown)
    @          0xb26e407  BLI_args_parse
    @          0x101c46b  main
    @     0x7f34eb952c87  __libc_start_main
    @          0x112d97c  (unknown)
```

Comment: I have the same issue... did you figure it out already?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`cuInit()` initializes the CUDA driver. It's not about what your device supports or doesn't support. Check your NVIDIA driver installation and whether your version of libcuda corresponds to it. In particualr, run `nvidia-smi` to check which driver is loaded, if at all, and which GPUs are visible.